# adding different types of user accounts in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, registration, user-roles, multiple-forms

I want to add 2 types of users in my wordpress website.I've read this post , but it's not providing any free method.

[Multiple User registration forms for different types of users in wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21655577/multiple-user-registration-forms-for-different-types-of-users-in-wordpress)

It'll be like "Buyer and Seller" , seller can add auctions and post stuff while buyer can bid. They both would have different access.
I want to verify seller and let them wait until approval while buyer can simply register.

These functions are what **"profile builder pro"** provide but I don't want to spend on it.
I've tried to use **"Ultimate Profile Builder"** , but when I add custom fields they don't appear in form.

I've also tried **WP registration** , it provide very clean forms but problem is that it don't have option to manage different roles - is this possible that I can manage both type of users with single registration form by providing different fields based on role selection(may be i can use radio button for role selection).

Comment: You'll need to [add role](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_role) your self, and then customize the registration. There are tons of tutorials for it, and it takes some time to program.

Answer (score 0):

It's easy you can learn about all wordpress users types, and whats roles given to all users, below screenshot

[image]